# Warning in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate an integral numerically, but I get the following warning message

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

and get no results. I tried to adjust the `PrecisionGoal` and `MaxRecursion` parameters for several values, but it still doesn't work. How can I fix this?

The integration mathematically is

\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_s=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{A^2\alpha_Q}{2(K-1)!\alpha_p}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}e^{-x}I(x)\,dx,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
I(x)=(-1)^{n-1}\left[\frac{A}{\alpha_p}+\frac{A^2\alpha_Q}{x\alpha_p}\right]^ne^{\frac{A}{\alpha_p}+\frac{A^2\alpha_Q}{x\alpha_p}}\text{Ei}\left(-\left[\frac{A}{\alpha_p}+\frac{A^2\alpha_Q}{x\alpha_p}\right]\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)!\left(-\left[\frac{A}{\alpha_p}+\frac{A^2\alpha_Q}{x\gamma_p}\right]\right)^{n-k},
\end{equation}
where $n=K-1$. The mathematical code is

```
alphap = 10^(0/10); 
ACont = 1; 
KPU = 2; 
NPU = KPU - 1; 
For[alphaQdB = -10, alphaQdB <= 5, alphaQdB++; alphaQ = 10^(alphaQdB/10); 
   Result = 0.5 - 0.5*((ACont^2*alphaQ)/((KPU - 1)!*alphap))*(-1)^(NPU - 1)*
      NIntegrate[(1/x)*(ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap))^NPU*
         Exp[ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap) - x]*
         ExpIntegralE[1, ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap)] + 
        Sum[(kk - 1)!*(-(ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap)))^
           (NPU - kk), {kk, 1, NPU}], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 50]; Print[Result]; ]
```

I hope the code format is OK. I copies and pasted it directly from *Mathematica* editor. Also, sorry, the integration expression isn't that pleasant, and that's why I hesitated to put it.

PS: $$-Ei(-x)=E_1(x)$$

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say anything meaningful without seeing the actual integral.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Edit your question to add that expression please, as well as the *Mathematica* code you used.

Comment: I was trying to put it here, but it was difficult. Thanks for the help. It's done in the original post.

Comment: The code is giving me a `MemoryAllocationFailure`, I have `16GB`.

Comment: Strange. I also have 16 GB and I don't get that message!!

Comment: The integral does not converge (pole of order 1 at x = 0) for many/all values of `alphaQdB`

Comment: @EngDavid (1) What version of Mathematica do you have? (2) Try copying the code you posted and execute it, to make sure you've posted the code correctly.

Comment: I use Mathematica 9. I executed the code I posted, and it's correct. Why? How can I solve the convergence problem?

Comment: @EngDavid Insert a Print[Plot[...YourIntegrand...,{x,0,10}]]; just before your Result= and see that it looks like in many cases your integrand is substantially greater than zero all the way out to infinity. You can optionally multiply your integrand by the expression you have outside the NIntegrate and the result is about the same. This is like asking how to "fix" that Integrate[5,{x,0,Infinity}] doesn't converge to a finite value.

Comment: OK, but the question is: would a correct mathematical derivation lead to a divergent integral?

Comment: (Site usage tip: Use @user to notify "user" of your response. Authors of posts are always notified.)  The divergence means the value of the integral is infinity.  If your interval of integration contained 0 in the interior, you could find the principal value. -- But as Bill points out, your integrand is also >1 in all cases.  You might want to check that it's correct.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I didn't understand quite well. Could you elaborate? What do you mean the integrand is >1 in all cases? and why is that a problem? I drew it, and although it goes to infinity at small values, at larger values it has a finite value. How can I attach it here? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `FullSimplify[integrand, x > 1]` returns [`True` for all values of `alphaQdB`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vLiDK.png). That means when you integrate out to infinity, the value will also approach infinity. -- Or was it this?: [`PrincipalValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrincipalValue.html) & [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: You seem to have the `1/x Exp[-x]` only multiplying the first part of the `I` expression.  Fixing that the integrand  goes to zero at infinity, but the integral now diverges at `0`...

Comment: You are also missing `G` but I don't think that affects convergence.

Comment: @george2079 Hi, sorry, that G is actually A. I fixed it. Yes, exactly, I have a problem at x=0, can I use a very small value close to 0 instead to fix this? I tried something like $$10^{-6}$$, but still the same same problem occurs!!

Comment: BTW: your exponential integral identity is wrong; the correct relationship is `-ExpIntegralEi[-z] == ExpIntegralE[1, z]`.

Comment: @J.M. That's correct. Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

too long for a comment.. lets look at your integrand:

```
alphap = 10^(0/10);
ACont = 1;
KPU = 2;
NPU = KPU - 1;
alphaQdB = -10;
alphaQ = 10^(alphaQdB/10);
(1/x)*(ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap))^NPU*
  Exp[ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap) - x]*
  ExpIntegralE[1, ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap)] + 
 Sum[(kk - 1)!*(-(ACont/alphap + (ACont^2*alphaQ)/(x*alphap)))^(NPU - 
      kk), {kk, 1, NPU}]
```

[image]

That constant `1` causes the infinite integral to diverge and as noted in comments arises because have failed to multiply the the `Exp[-x]/x` through the entire `I` expression.

fixing that,

[image]

you get a convergent integral on the infinite domain, so long as you avoid zero.

Without knowing the application its not clear what the point would be of setting the lower bound to some arbitrary finite value since the result will depend strongly on the selected value.

Comment: OMG, you are right, I just noticed that. The second part that includes the summation in I isn't multiplied by Exp[-x]/x. I don't have access to Mathematica right now, but you're saying that the integral still doesn't give results in the range between 0 and infinity because of the zero lower bound, is that correct? The idea of arbitrary small value for the lower bound is to evaluate the integral as close as possible to the zero lower bound such that it's integrable to get results.

Comment: right you can do `NIntegrate[ .. , {x,10^-6,Infinity}]` and it converges (~25 for this example)

Comment: Thanks. I will check this when I have access to my computer.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked it, and the integral is evaluated to a finite value now, even with the zero lower bound. Thanks again for notifying me on the the missing term.

Comment: OK, now when I change KPU to 3 I get warning message: overflow, indeterminate, or infinity!! Why with KPU=2 it works while with KPU=3 it doesn't?!